# limpiar formulario de bootstrap

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Tengo un formulario en bootstrap, lo lleno, guardo cambios, y luego vuelvo a abrir en la misma ventana para ingresar nuevos datos al formulario, pero me aparecen los datos anteriores, es decir, no se limpia si vuelvo a abrir la misma ventana.

Este es mi código:

```html
 <div class="modal fade" id="generaFolio">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">  
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <!-- Header de la ventana-->
                                        <div class="modal-header"> 
                                            <button tyle="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"> &times; </button>
                                            <h3 class="modal-title"><strong> Introduzca la siguiente información </strong></h3>
                                        </div>

<form role="form" id="folio">
    <div class="form-group" >
        <label for="nombrePropietario">Nombre Propietario:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombrePropietario" placeholder="Introduzca nombre del propietario">
        <br><br>
        <label for="nombreSolicitante">Nombre del solicitante:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombreSolicitante" placeholder="Introduzca nombre del solicitante">
        <br><br>
        <label for="fecha" class="col-xs-3">Fecha de solicitud:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="día" maxlength="2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Mes" maxlength="10">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Año" maxlength="4">
        </div>
        <br><br>    <br><br> 
        <label for="hora"  class="col-xs-4">Hora: <p class="text-muted"></p></label>                                                    
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="input-group" >
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="hora" maxlength="2">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><strong>:</strong></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="min" maxlength="2">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br><br><br>                                          
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Limpiar"> 
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"> Cerrar </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" > Guardar cambios </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Agrégale un *ID* a tu formulario y posteriormente puedes hacerlo con **JQUERY**, te dejo 2 opciones:

1. Primera Opción

   `$('#miFormulario')[0].reset();`
2. Segunda Opción

   `$('#miFormulario').trigger("reset");`

---

***Edición por continuidad***

Debes asociar el `$('#miFormulario').trigger("reset");` al botón:  `<button>Cerrar</button>` de la siguiente forma:

Primero debes agregar la propiedad `id="btnCerrar"` al botón:

```
<button id="btnCerrar" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"> Cerrar </button>
```

Posteriormente hay que agregarle el evento al botón:

```
$("#btnCerrar").on("click",function(event){ 
     event.prevenDefault(); 
     $('#miFormulario').trigger("reset"); 
});
```

Comment: oye ¿y no importa que mi formulario tenga class="modal fade" ?porque pongo ese código y no funciona

Comment: No debería, que error te arroja?

Comment: pues simplemente me sigue haciendo lo mismo, no se limpia el formulario al cerrar la ventana

Comment: Ok coloca el código que estas usando para llamar el `script` que yo te he dejado.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> $('#folio')[0].reset();  </script>

Comment: "folio" es como llamé a mi formulario

Comment: Listo, ya he actualizado la respuesta, solo debes adecuarlo a tus necesidades particulares.

Comment: no pues no me queda u_u

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41522/discussion-between-alfonso-carrasco-and-abraxas).

Answer (score 0):

Sólo debes llamar el input usando el atributo `id` con javascript o jquery. Por ejemplo:

```
<input name="nomPropietario" type="text" class="form-control" id="nombrePropietario" placeholder="Introduzca nombre del propietario" >
```

Entonces con jquery lo llamas y dejas en blanco como sigue:

```
$('#nombrePropietario').val("");
```

Debes hacer eso con cada input de tu formulario cada vez que presiones el boton "Guardar Cambios"